# How do I only allow numbers in a JTextField using a KeyEvent?

Tags: java, swing, formatting, textfield, keyevent

My attempt at this is:

```
private void jTextField1KeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                       
        char c = evt.getKeyChar();

        if(c != '1' && c != '2' && c != '3' && c != '4' 
           && c != '5' && c != '6' && c != '7' && c != '8'
           && c != '9' && c != '0') {
            evt.consume(); 
        }
```

Which is quite strange, since this is what my book has shown me.

Also, is this viable in comparison to a Formatted Text Field?

Comment: what is your current result from the above code? does it word?

Comment: Well, even though this is fixed, it would do nothing except for not allowing the backspace and delete buttons to function.

Comment: don't use keyEvents, they are way too low-level and unsafe for validation (f.i can't cope with pasted code). Instead, use a DocumentFilter or a JFormattedTextField

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing your `if (Mile of tests)` with:

```
    if(c < '0' || c > '9')
        evt.consume();
```

or, the more readable, as azurefrog pointed out:

```
    if(!Character.isDigit(c))
        evt.consume();
```

Comment: Got the conditions backwards, changed my answer

Comment: I am kind of confused why this fixed my problem; could you explain?

Comment: Also should you use `if(c <= '0' || c >= '9')` instead?

Comment: @Eypros Nope. If we do that, then 0 and 9 would be consumed instead of performed.

Comment: @user3758041 `char`s are glorified (and unsigned) `short`s. You can add, divide, modulo, ect... them as you would with any other primitive numeric type. This includes comparing them with operators. If you want the full list of characters in order, [here](http://www.ascii-code.com/) is one.

Comment: It might be more readable to just use `Character.isDigit(c)` instead of manually checking.

Comment: @Azurefrog That seems quite more efficient. That should be an answer.

Comment: @Sebastian Makes sense, but that still doesn't explain why my old code didn't worked.

Comment: By attempting to explicitly make 10 tests in one `if` statement, you are bound to make a mistake/typo. Shorter is usually better. By cleaning it up like so, you make the code infinitely more readable and, in cases such as this, faster.

Answer (score 4):

You should never use `KeyListener`s with text components

For one, it doesn't take into account what happens when the user pastes text into the field.  It's also possible that the key event could be consumed and never reach your listener

Swing has a number of components which might fulfill your needs

- [`JSpinner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html)
- [`JFormattedTextField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html)

Both these are capable of restricting user input to numbers and I'm the case of the `JSpinner`, ranges of numbers

These fields are post processing, that is, they will allow the user to enter what ever they want, but will validate the value when the loses focus or the user accepts the value

If you want real time filtering you should use a [`DocumentFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html%23filter), for [examples](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the backspace and delete button to function then you need to put them inside your if statement

**sample:**

```
if(c != '1' && c != '2' && c != '3' && c != '4' 
               && c != '5' && c != '6' && c != '7' && c != '8'
               && c != '9' && c != '0') || !(c == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) ||
               !(c == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE)){
                evt.consume(); 
            }
```